# send an array from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I want to send an array using a variable from view to controller, so that I can use it to get some data from database according to that array!
For example, in my view I will have a variable with different equations like:

```
$data = 'setter';
```

and somewhere else:

```
$data = 'libero';
```

Then in my controller I will have a code like:

```
if($query = $this->players_model->get_players(array('player_Position' => $data, 'limit' => 3))) { $data['players'] = $query; }
```

what should I do to get it work?!

Comment: Use a form to send the values from your View to Controller. Suggest that you check out this tutorial series http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve passing an array from a view to a controller is un-logic , check better what a MVC is ;)

Comment: I just wanted to shorten the ways! thanks for informing me of this :)

Comment: @cartalot, I don't wanna use form in my view file! and that's why I was looking for another way!

Comment: ok then you want jquery ! that will send values from View to Controller. google for tutorials: Codeigniter jquery - use their code to learn, then modify for your project.

Answer (score 3):

first i would like to advise you , that whatever you are trying to achieve, the "pass an array from a view to a controller" is wrong , MVC pattern is not standing for passing data from view to a controller.

Then, i'l do like this:

```
//in view
$data = json_encode($myArray);

//in controller

$array = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use session userdata

**View**

```
$data = array(
    'setter'  => 'value',
    'libero'  => 'value'
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

**Controller**

```
$setter = $this->session->userdata('setter');
$libero = $this->session->userdata('libero');
```

or

```
$data['setter'] = $this->session->userdata('setter');
$data['libero'] = $this->session->userdata('libero');
```